# Making independent graphs for different event types

Tags: azure-application-insights

The application insights APIs let you record custom events for user-defined purposes. They also let you record custom properties on those events.

The Application Insights chart control on the Azure Portal however, appears to have some annoying limitation.

Let's say we have two event names:

- *Login*: A user logged in.
- *Work*: The application started some expensive background job, which happens independently of any user action on various conditions.

Then I likely don't want those event types to be series in the same chart. In particular, I may want to do a grouping by user or something similar in case of *Login*, but that would make no sense for the *Work* type.

They really have nothing to do with each other and I'd like to have them in different charts.

I do, however, want them to be in the same chart control (the whole white rectangle thing that groups charts together and where you set the time scope and filters on).

The following missing features would each solve the problem:

- If it was allowed to set a filter on individual charts rather than only the chart control as a whole.
- If each event name would appear as a distinct metric to select.

I know there's also Analytics, but then I still don't have the new chart in the same old chart control.

Is there another option I overlooked?

Comment: Do you mind adding a screenshot of what you have and what you are expecting? That'll just make it a whole lot easier to visualize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in any one specific metrics explorer window, like you said, filters apply to the whole window.

But you can do this by creating a dashboard, and pinning individual metrics explorer charts (or grids, or whatever) to that dashboard.

1. make a new dashboard, and name it something distinctive
2. create one of the charts you want with the right filters in a standard metrics explorer part.
3. pin that chart to the dashboard created in step 1.
4. repeat steps 2 and 3 to create each chart with its own settings
5. go to that dashboard, and resize / configure each chart the way you want it

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. The workaround is feasible, it's only drawback is that the time selections aren't kept in sync.

Comment: i want to say that's already a suggestion on the azure uservoice site (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal?query=dashboard) but i can't for the life of me find it.  i thought they'd already done something for this?